Question about application of Montel's Theorem

Lemma Suppose that $f_n : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ is holomorphic. If $z \in \mathbb{D}$ and $|f_n(z)| \to 1$, then $|f_n(w)| \to 1$ for every $w \in \mathbb{D}$.

Proof: Suppose that conclusion fails. Then, there exists $w \in \mathbb{D}$ and a subsequence $(f_{n_j})$ such that $f_{n_j}(w) \to \alpha$ with $|\alpha| < 1$. Now Montel's Theorem shows that $(f_{n_j})$ has a further subsequence which converges uniformly on compact sets to $f \in H(\mathbb{D})$. It is clear that $|f| \le 1$ in $\mathbb{D}$. [...]
My question is: How prove that $|f| \le 1$ in $\mathbb{D}$? Thanks!
Edit: Ok. So what I understood: From hypothesis we have that $|f_n(z)| \le 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$. And, because $f$ is uniform convergent on compact sets to $f$, uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, and every point of $\mathbb{D}$ is a compact set, implies that $\forall z \in \mathbb{D}$ we have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(z) = f(z)$. But because $|f_n(z)| \le 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$, we have that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} |f_n(z)| \le 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$. But, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} |f_n(z)| = |f(z)| \le 1$ for all $z\in \mathbb{D}$. And the property of uniform convergence on compact sets implies that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$.

$|f_n| \le 1$ is given in the hypothesis so any limit function of $f_n$ satisfies same

@Conrad yes but it says that it converges on compact sets and this confuses me a little bit... If you can explain in detail would be nice.

for every $|z| <1$ we have $|f_n(z)| \le1$ by hypothesis but then any limit point of  the sequence $f_n(z)$ satisfies same by general limit properties; uniform convergence on compacts of a subsequence of $f_n$ is also pointwise (for example every point is a compact set by itself!), so at every fixed $z$, the result is a limit point of $f_n(z)$; note that uniform convergence on compacts is needed for the conclusion that the resulting function is holomorphic but not for pointwise estimates where just simple convergence works

@Conrad I've added an edit with what I've understood. Can you check it please and say me if it's ok? Thanks!

Looks correct by and large - the only thing is that you have a subsequence of $f_n$ that converges not necessarily all $f_n$ but the argument about $|f|\le 1$ then is correct

@Conrad oh. Ok. You're right. I forgot that I work with a subsequence. Thanks you for your help, not only with this question. For all your answers to my questions!

Happy to be of help
